# How to retrieve objects property info from data binding

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml, xamarin, xamarin.forms

I have a Xamarin Forms application where I populate a list view with a list of objects of type `Student`. I want to be able to select this student and open an alert that displays the name of the student selected. My current attempt only displays the type of the object (`Student`) in the alert. Here is my approach:

`AttendancePage.xaml:`

```
<ListView x:Name="RosterInView" SeparatorVisibility="None" ItemSelected="OnSelection">
    <ListView.ItemTemplate>
        <DataTemplate>
            <TextCell Text="{Binding complete_name}"
            Detail="{Binding grade}"/>
        </DataTemplate>
    </ListView.ItemTemplate>
</ListView>
```

And in my `AttendancePage.xaml.cs` I'm having difficulty getting the binding property down:

```
protected override void OnAppearing()
    {
        base.OnAppearing();
        IEnumerable<Student> roster = _database.GetItems();

        RosterInView.ItemsSource = roster;

    }
void OnSelection(object sender, SelectedItemChangedEventArgs e)
    {
        if (e.SelectedItem == null)
            return;
        // real trouble starts here with how to refer to "complete_name" as seen in the xaml file
        DisplayAlert("Item Selected", ((ListView)sender).SelectedItem.ToString(), "OK");
    }
```

Comment: (((ListView)sender).SelectedItem as Student) doesn't work for you?

Comment: Thats it! thank you!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Pretty simple solution thanks to @RoyiMindel for pointing it out, instead of

```
 DisplayAlert("Item Selected", ((ListView)sender).SelectedItem.ToString(), "OK");
```

it should be:

```
DisplayAlert("Item Selected", (((ListView)sender).SelectedItem as Student).complete_name, "OK");
```